# How to find length of array of array

Tags: tcl

I would like to find length of array of array

Here is my code

```
array set partarray
Set n [array size partarray ]
```

But partarray is again an array with

```
Partarray =

Partarray(EIDS)= 1 2 3

Partarray(NIDS)= 3 2 5 4 3

Partarray(PIDS)= 2 3 4....
```

Now I have to find the length of 
Partarray(PIDS)?

So can anyone help me with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly array of array. In Tcl, it's just a way of convenience to simulate multi-dimensional array.

So, from Tcl's perspective, it's just an array with 3 elements and each element having a list of elements associated with it.

If you deliberately wanted to know, then you can loop through the array and for each element get the array size.

```
% array set u {}
% set u(1) 1
1
% set u(2) 2
2
% array set f {}
% set f(a) [array get u]
1 1 2 2
% array size f
1
% array size u
2
%
```

Comment: I have tried with   : array set partarray
                                 Set n [array size partarray {3}]   and puts $n but it's not working. I am very new to tcl,  can you please let me know mistake

Comment: As mentioned, you should loop the array and then try `array size` for each element

Comment: You can use a glob pattern with `array get` to limit the keys which are returned. For example, `array get u 12,*`. And use `llength $Partarray(PIDS)` for the length of a _list_ in an array element.